# How to edit vocabulary machine name?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, migrations

I migrated my site from lower version of drupal, during migration process the machine name of my vocabularies was changed, now I want to modify them manually, but I cant find the proper table in database. now the question is :

> How can I edit vocabularies machine name manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the machine name of your vocabulary is: **test**.

Then you can use the following code

```
$vid= 'test';

$vocabulary= taxonomy_vocabulary_load($vid);

$vocabulary->set('name', trim('newmachinename'));

$vocabulary->save();
```

> change the **newmachinename** by your machine name.

**Note**. you must be careful when using this code, because those configurations that you have with the previous machine name will be affected

Comment: Will this break any configuration that already points to the old machine name?  If so, you should warn about that.

Comment: is correct, but since he is in the process of migrating the data, we assume that he is not referring to the old name machine.

Comment: My understanding of the question is that the migration is over, which means the migration process may have moved other things (views, etc.) to use the new machine name.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create new vocabulary.
$vid = 'site_press_centre';
$name = 'News';
$vocabularies = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Vocabulary::loadMultiple();
if (!isset($vocabularies[$vid])) {
  $vocabulary = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Vocabulary::create(array(
        'vid' => $vid,
        'name' => $name,
  ));
  $vocabulary->save();
}

// Update current terms.
$vid_old = 'press_centre';
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term');
$query->condition('vid', $vid_old);
$tids = $query->execute();
foreach ($tids as $tid) {
    $term = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($tid);
    if (!empty($term)) {
      $term->vid = $vid;
      $term->save();
    }
}

// Delete old vocabulary.
$vocabulary = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_vocabulary')->load($vid_old)->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to round this question up, if you do have access to the migration YAML files, you can already set the new vocabulary names during the migration.

```
process:
  vid:
    -
      plugin: make_unique_entity_field
      source: machine_name
      entity_type: taxonomy_vocabulary
      field: vid
      length: 32
      migrated: true
    -
      plugin: forum_vocabulary
      machine_name: forums
    -
      plugin: static_map
      map:
        vocabulary_1: new_vocab_1
        vocabulary_2: new_vocab_2
        vocabulary_3: new_vocab_3
      bypass: TRUE
```

The last plugin in the chain allows you to rename machine names of vocabularies, in the above example, these are originally Drupal 6 names (vocabulary_X) which where now transferred into proper  vocab names.

The `bypass: TRUE` allows the migration to leave any other machine name that is not in the list to remain untouched. The opposite would be to set a default value, which will be returned instead if the name is not in the list.